# Setting One to One

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

I have a Rails 4 app which has a Devise user. The Devise user can create multiple Apps and each App can contain multiple Certificates. At any given time tho and App can only have one production_certificate and one development_certificate. I believe that i setup the associations correctly here they are. My trouble now is how can i set the App to use one out of the many Certificates that an app owns to be the production/development certificate.

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :certificates

  belongs_to :production_certificate, class_name: 'Certificate'
  belongs_to :development_certificate, class_name: 'Certificate'
end

class Certificate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :app
end
```

Comment: Do you want to know how to use these associations to save the data correctly?

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand what you want to do. If you just picked the first certificate to be the blessed certificate, that would work, but I doubt it is the answer you want. So, tell us why that is a bad answer.

Comment: @Bigxiang yes I'm trying to figure out how to save the data correctly.

Comment: @Fred ^ I'm wondering how to save the data correctly

Comment: So what results are you getting with your current code? (Your final sentence appears to ask for help selecting a certificate, which is why I asked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to answer your question.

I suppose that you have an app object and some certificate objects.

At first, you get an App object.

```
app = App.find(YOUR ID)

app.certificates.each do |c|
  # In the loop, you can set your logic 
  # that selects which certificate is production certificate 
  # or development certificate

  if .....
    app.production_certificate = c

  elsif .....

    app.development_certificate = c
  end

end

app.save
```

I'm not sure the answer can solve your problem. If you have any question, please comment below.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem and works perfectly. Is there anyway i can find out if a certificate if being used by an app programmatically from the certificate model?

Comment: If a certificate is used by an app, then user_id of certificate must not be null. so you can use Certificate.where('user_id is not null') get all certificates is used. It returns an ActiveRecord::Relation, you can use it as an array.